# Elementary OS 5.1 Hera (based Ubuntu 18.04) automatic logout session occasionally

Tags: release-hera, greeter, desktop, shutdown, session

occasionally my pc with elementary os 5.1 (based on Ubuntu 18.04) makes automatic logout session. This problem comes up, after minutes, when I change virtual desktop (ex. clicking on telegram notify that it's in 3rd desktop). No system error messages appear, simply operating system goes to login screen, closing all my work.

Everything has been updated, video driver and operating system.

I don't know what I have to see for resolving this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A PR for this error was merged today. Here is the related issue: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/766

Answer (score 0):

Same. I am thinking about migration to another linux dist, cause this error is really annoying. I work on ElementaryOS and during my workday (8 hours) system can logout something around 2-3 times. I am preety sure this problem has appeared after last update - 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same issue as well.

Reading through https://github.com/elementary/gala/pull/780, I see a fix listed here:

https://github.com/elementary/gala/commit/3f7cb0e251e842a3abc603be8cb0d26f8a478953

However, I'm unable to locate src/WindowManager.vala to perform the recommended edits.

For now, I'll just disable System Settings>Tweaks>Animations to see if that ameliorates it, and wait for an official fix.  If none comes about, Elementary OS gets replaced as this issue makes it too unstable to production use.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue with Elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir.
Sometimes when I get a lot of notifications in a row from slack, my curent work window freezed one second turning semi blank.
Sometimes it just shows a black screen with a blinking cursor and I got logged out. Pretty annoying if you have a alot of windows open.